# why do i get 403 request when trying to get available balance from kraken C++

Tags: c++, openssl, c++-chrono, kraken.com

im using open ssl, cpr and chrono to access krakens restful api to recieve account balance from kraken, but i get a 403 request.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cpr/cpr.h>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cpr;
using namespace chrono;
using json = nlohmann::json;


int main(){

    //variables
    string key = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
    string secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    string baseUrl =  
             "https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance";

    //get nonce
    const auto p1 = system_clock::now();
    int T1 = duration_cast<seconds>(p1.time_since_epoch()).count();
    string timestamp = to_string(t1);
    string postData = "nonce=" + timestamp;

    //get signature
    string rPath = "/0/private/Balance";
    string message = rpath + timestamp + postData;

    unsigned char hmac_result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
    unsigned int hmac_result_len;
    HMAC(
        EVP_sha256(),
        secret.c_str(), secret.length(),
        (unsigned char*)message.c_str(), message.length(),
        hmac_result, &hmac_result_len
    );

    string signature = string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(hmac_result), 
                              hmac_result_len);


    //cpr request
    Response r;

    Header header;
    header.insert({ "API-Key", key });
    header.insert({ "API-Sign", signature });

    r = Post(Url{ baseUrl }, Body{ postData }, Header{ header });
    cout << "Status Code: " << r.status_code << endl;
    cout << r.text << endl;
}
```

the response i get is:

```
Status Code: 403
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <title>That is Not Allowed</title>
    <style type="text/css">body,html{height:100%;width:100%}body{background-color:#0d0c52;color:#fff;font-family:Helvetica,sans-serif;margin:0}article{display:grid;grid-template-columns:100%;grid-template-rows:auto 1fr auto;min-height:100%}footer,header{background-color:#5740d9;padding:34px 0 30px 40px}main{align-items:center;display:inline-grid;grid-template-columns:50% 50%;padding:50px 0}main>div:first-child{padding-left:30%}@media (max-width:800px){main{grid-template-columns:100%}main>div:first-child{padding:0 40px}main>div:last-child{display:none}}a{color:#fff}</style>
  </head>
```

the rest of the text seems to be krakens logo source(which is like 2 pages long). if you me to include it please let me know!

Comment: Perhaps invalid credentials are used.

Comment: i copied and pasted them from kraken so i doubt it

Comment: `Header{ header })` What is a purpose of copying headers to a temporary object?

Comment: The only purpose this serves it to make the code more neat and easy to read, atleast thats what i figured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. Error 403, it's on your end. It could be:

- The key could have expired
- The URL is not correct. Which was the case (`baseUrl = "https://api.kraken.com/";`  instead of `"baseUrl = https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance";`, since you already specified the path in `rpath`)
- Https communication requires a certificate. I assume you're using the openssl library correctly. But you might check that.

Trial and error and you'll eventually find the problem.

Options to help:

- To debug http/https errors like these, I also recommend (if you have the time) to download some software which can send and help debug your requests (**Postman** is a good recommendation! Easy to use). Helps plenty when debugging/double-checking issues like the one above.
- If you happen to use linux or any sort of terminal which has *curl* installed, you could try it using the `--verbose` parameter (it shows useful info!). Example of use:

  curl --verbose --location --request POST 'https://api.kraken.com/0/private/Balance' 
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
  --data-urlencode '... other params if required ...' 
  --data-urlencode 'API-Key=XXXXXXX' 
  --data-urlencode 'API-Sign=XXXXXXX'

Comment: i tried this and still same request

Comment: This is a wrong guess. `Header` is just a map of `<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: @273K Thanks for the tip. I wanted to comment since I was could be sure it wouldn't be that (but not enough reputation so meh, shoot my shot). I corrected my answer and added something more useful.

Comment: my path was specified incorrectly. i changed it to your suggestion and recieved a status code 200. thank you!

Comment: I figured I could be repeated after you specified it both on the baseUrl AND on rpath. You're welcome. We beginners gotta stick together! hahah